# VB.NET - Debugging and DataSets?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, dataset

Anyway to view the content of a dataset or datatable in debug?  I don't mean looking up a specific element of the dataset but to view the hole thing.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337084/how-to-view-a-datatable-while-debuging

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Just use the **DataSet Visualizer**.  See [this MSDN article about how to use DataTips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea46xwzd%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

When you're in Debug stepping through code, just hover over the DataSet and click on the little magnifying glass that is there to open the visualizer.

Comment: I don't get the visualizer and what I do get does not give a view of the data of all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [RightHand dataset visualiser](http://www.rthand.com/DesktopModules/Articles/ArticlesView.aspx?tabID=0&alias=RightHand&lang=en-US&ItemID=15&mid=10244) particulary useful on many occasions, particulary when debugging constraint errors as it will show you what constraint has been broken and which rows are in error - something the built in visualiser doesn't do as well showing what rows have been added/changed/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a particularly large and complex dataset where 'hovering' wouldn't be practical, you can also use the command window.  To print values from a dataset, you could use something like the following:

```
? dsMyDataSet.Tables("NameOfTable").Rows(1).Item("NameOfColumn")
```

...which would return the value of the named column in the second row (0-based) of the named table in the dataset.

or

```
? dsMyDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
```

...which would return the value of the first column of the first row of the first table in the dataset.

Comment: >>I don't mean looking up a specific element of the dataset but to view the hole thing.