# when debugging, where is data stored in dataset

Tags: asp.net, debugging, dataset, sqldatasource

I am debugging and I can't find where the data is stored. Here is

[image]

This is how I reference the cells in C# code.

```
txtCompanyName.Text = aCustomerDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CompanyName"].ToString();
```

Can someone give more insight into, what static members store and what non-static. I am familiar with static concept myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static member of a dataset would show something that is true for all datasets in the entire appdomain. That is such a peculiar scenario, I can only imagine that that is not what you want.

I think you are trying to get at the dataset visualizer, i.e. to show the cells of a table in a dataset.

[How to view a DataTable while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337084/how-to-view-a-datatable-while-debugging)