# C# SQL query output to Excel not including newly added fields in output

Tags: c#, sql, excel, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have a small button click code which outputs a SQL query to Excel.

This worked fine until I added a new field in the table it queries and now it is still outputting the same fields and not including the new one.

Code:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM Services";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLQuery, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook ExcelWorkBook = null;
            Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet = null;
            ExcelApp.Visible = true;
            ExcelApp.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMinimized;
            ExcelApp.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
            ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            List<string> SheetNames = new List<string>();
            SheetNames.Add("Services Details");
            ExcelApp.ActiveWindow.Activate();
            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                    ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Add();
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                {
                    int r = 1;
                    ExcelWorkSheet = ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets[i + 1];
                    ExcelWorkSheet.Name = "Services";
                    for (int col = 1; col < ds.Tables[i].Columns.Count; col++)
                        ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = ds.Tables[i].Columns[col - 1].ColumnName;
                    r++;
                    for (int row = 0; row < ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 1; col < ds.Tables[i].Columns.Count; col++)
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = ds.Tables[i].Rows[row][col - 1].ToString();
                        r++;
                    }
                    ExcelWorkSheet.Rows[1].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
                    ExcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
                }
                ExcelApp.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkSheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkBook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
            }
            catch (Exception exHandle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + exHandle.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

I have also tried explicitly querying the new field `SELECT ABC FROM Services` and nothing is output.

There are values in the new fields.

If I run the same query on Azure query editor preview I get the correct results.

> EDIT

Ok so I changed the query to `SELECT *,1 FROM Services` and then I get all the fields (bar the new "1" field) how can I change the loop to get all fields?

> EDIT 2 SOLUTION Using EPPlus

Just to update anyone looking at this in the future, I used the `NuGet Package Manager` (`Project` > `Manage NuGet Packages`) and installed `EPPlus` by Jan Kallmän.

I then added:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
```

And used the following code on the button:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM Services";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLQuery, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        using (var p = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Service");
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
            int totalRows = ws.Dimension.End.Row;
            int totalCols = ws.Dimension.End.Column;
            var headerCells = ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, totalCols];
            var headerFont = headerCells.Style.Font;
            headerFont.Bold = true;
            var allCells = ws.Cells[1, 1, totalRows, totalCols];
            allCells.AutoFitColumns();
            p.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"d:\excel\Service" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".xlsx"));
        }
    }
```

This is an instant output to a file and thanks to @[Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard)

Comment: for starters, don't use `Microsoft.Office.Interop`. This requires Excel to be installed (license cost), is very slow, and can pop-up error messages or other user prompts that will hang your application, waiting for a human to respond. Instead, use the [OOXML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), which is an official library from Microsoft to manipulate Office files. Better yet, use [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus), which wraps OOXML SDK with easy to use API.

Comment: Although this is probably not the problem of the OP, in some database systems, a "COMMIT" must be made before new rows are actually there.  Furthermore, sometimes it will appear they are there (temporarily), but they won't be there once the window that inserted/created them will be there.  Just a warning for people who read this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First up, I second the comment about using EPPlus. I think it even has a method to turn a datatable into a sheet, so this click event handler could be boiled down to about 4 lines of code. Take a look over this SO question - [Export DataTable to excel with EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus)

Second, I think your actual problem is a simple off-by-one error

You said (my paraphrase)

> if I use a query that returns one column, like `select abc from services`, nothing is output

Here's how you're doing your column output:

```
for(int col = 1; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
```

Your table has one column. The comparison to run the loop is thus: `is 1 less than 1?`

False

Loop doesn't run

If your table had 10 columns, the loop would run 9 times. The last column will never be output. You've got a query with a new column on the end, you're expecting to see it, it's not there because your c# doesn't output it, not because there is something weird about the data in the column..

In terms of what to do about it, change the comparison you do in the "should loop run" part:

```
for(int col = 1; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)
```

Or change the way you index (index by 0 instead of index by 1):

```
for(int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
  excel[row, col+1] = table[row][col]; //excel is 1 based, c# is 0 based
```

Regarding those notions of "but the data hasn't changed, and the code hasn't changed, and something different is observed" - it's almost never the case. It's far more likely that something is being misremembered by the human in the equation. Maybe the first guy that wrote the code hit the same issue and just duplicated the last column in the SQL to get around it, then you/someone else saw it and though "that looks wrong, i'll just take that out..", then months later you're looking and going "this used to work, i'm sure it did..."

:)

But seriously; use EPPlus ;) it's delightful, easy, creates xlsx files directly (they're just xml files inside a zip, renamed to xlsx) and is super simple. Excel COM is a massive headache, and you'd be needlessly building a tech support nightmare for yourself. With EPPlus (use nuget package manager to add a reference to EPPlus) your code would look more like:

```
using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM services", "PUT YOUR CONN STRING IN A CONFIG FILE")){
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
      ExcelWorksheet ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheetname");
      ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
      ep.SaveAs(new FileInfo("YOUR SAVE PATH HERE"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the EPPlus example and see if I can reduce the code, what I don't understand is the code hasn't changed but the output hasn't changed to the new field, seems rather strange.

Comment: Also i am getting an error under `table` when using `for(int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)`

Comment: Ok it is the loop that is breaking it, I changed the query to `SELECT *,1 FROM Services` and then I get all the fields (bar the new "1" field) how can i change the loop to get all fields?

Comment: use <= instead of <

Comment: innermost loop which write the dt contents to the worksheet cells

Comment: Also be aware that if the datatable is large and you still use Interop, then it will be slow. You should write the whole thing in that case, but that's another story...

Comment: this answer is better than mine. +1 for a perfect example of when to use a code comment

Answer (score 3):

Is "Services" a table or a view? You might be seeing results from an outdated schema (cached before you made your change). This is a danger with "select *". Try an explicit field list instead of "*".

Comment: As i said in my question, its a table and I have already tried selecting the new field explicitly.

Comment: you didn’t say _how_ you tried the more specific select. was it through the c# code? i thought you might have meant that you tried it in a sql query tool, which would not reveal the problem i mentioned. To many developers “table” is used as a general reference to any object being selected from. I wasn’t sure how specifically to take that.

Comment: I tried both, amending the sql query in c# to be explicit and also in azure query

Comment: then i would probably create a test button with just a ds fill and screen dump to see if the issue is in that or the excel export stuff.

Comment: Incidentally, if you’re working with datasets VS has had a dataset visualiser for years.. place a breakpoint after you fill your set/table, point to the dataset/table variable and wait for the tooltip to appear, click the magnifying glass.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337084/how-to-view-a-datatable-while-debugging for more